# Dúvida no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Preciso da seguinte fórmula:
Se salário menor que R$ 1399,12, calcule 8%
Se salário maior que R$ 1399,13 e menor que R$ 2331,88, calcule 9%
Se salário maior que R$ 2331,89 e menor que R$ 4663,75, calcule 11%

Comment: O que é que já tentaste até ao momento?

Comment: isso é tão simples que é possível resolver somente na barra de fórmulas..

Answer (score 3):

levando em consideração que sua referência estará na célula A1,  você pode usar a seguinte fórmula:

```
=SE(A1<=1399,12;A1*8%;SE(E(A1>=1399,13;A1<=2331,88);A1*9%;SE(E(A1>=2331,89;A1<=4663,75);A1*11%;"extrapolou")))
```